# Java Generics : Obtaining a Class<Collection<T>>?

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble using generics. Given the following example :

```
class A<T> {
  public A(Class<T> myType){
  }
}

class B<E> extends A<Collection<E>> {
  public B(Class<E> myEType){
    super(???);
  }
}
```

What ??? should be ?
`Collection.class` don't work...
`Collection<E>.class` neither.
`(Class<Collection<E>>)Collection.class` do not work...

If there is a java generics guru, I need help... :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't possibly get a `Class<Collection<E>>` except for `Collection.class`, because of type erasure.  You'll have to use unsafe casts to cast a `Collection.class` to a `Class<Collection<E>>` -- specifically, `(Class<Collection<E>>) (Class) Collection.class` will do the job.

Comment: In addition to my answer below, like Louis I would suggest reading and understanding Java "type erasure" completely.

Comment: I agreed on type erasure. But casting like '(Class<Collection<E>>)Collection.class' produce 'Cannot cast from Class<Collection> to Class<Collection<E>' in eclipse :(

Comment: Use `Class<Collection<E>> clazz = (Class) Collection.class`.  Evil but it works.

Comment: (Class<Collection<E>>)(Class)Collection.class, yes it works and sometime, evil seem the only solution ;) Thanks Louis (If you post it as answer, I'll check it as answered).

Answer (score 1):

```
class A<T> {
    public A(Class<T> myType){
    }
}

class B<E> extends A<Collection<E>> {
    public B(Class<Collection<E>> myEType){ // <-- this is the changed line
        super(myEType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But it seem you only moved the problem, with your modification, how can I construct B ? The question become "new B(???);", but the ??? is still there :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class A<T> {
  public A(Class<?> myType){
  }
}

class B<E> extends A<Collection<E>> {
  public B(Class<E> myEType){
    super(myEType);
  }
}
```

If satisfied, please mark this answer correct.

Comment: Thanks brettw, but I'm not satisfied with this. The class A become unsafe and it's what I'm trying to avoid :/

Comment: @brettw: to mark something as code, don't use the `<pre>` tag, simply indent it by 4 or more spaces (the "{}" button will do this for a block for you. For this post, I've corrected it for you. Also, when you properly mark the code this way, you no longer need to use HTML escape sequences and you will get syntax hilighting :-)