# Class Type casting compile error

Tags: java, collections, casting, compilation, type-parameter

I have a code, interestingly Intellij complains at make process (while running javac, not by jit) when I try to run main:

```
public class Foo {


      public static void main(String[] args) {
         RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
         String restEndPointUrl = "";
         Integer userId = 0;

         ResponseEntity<? extends ArrayList<Foo>> responseEntity =
            restTemplate.getForEntity(restEndPointUrl, (Class<? extends ArrayList<Foo>>) ArrayList.class, userId);
      }
   }
```

In which `getForEntity` has the signature:

`public <T> ResponseEntity<T> getForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object... urlVariables)`

error:

```
Error:(77, 94) java: inconvertible types
  required: java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.ArrayList<Foo>>
  found:    java.lang.Class<java.util.ArrayList>
```

java version: 1.7.0_60
In fact what i wanted to ask is not related to intellij, but it's about java compilation. Could someone clearly explain the rules behind that?

Code is taken from [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8263?focusedCommentId=117001&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-117001).

I also looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508663/java-generics-obtaining-a-classcollectiont/9508760#9508760) answer however it does not tell me much of the logic behind generics and typecasting works.

Furthermore, should (or can) I simply replace `? extends ArrayList<Foo>` or `? super ArrayList<Foo>` like expressions with `ArrayList<Foo>`, while trying to solve those kind of questions, which are very likely to exist in java certification exams? Certainly learning the "why" will help me learning sort of approaches I should take for them.

Comment: @RealSkeptic sorry, question edited.

Comment: `restTemplate.getForEntity(restEndPointUrl, new ArrayLisr<Foo>().getClass, userId);`